# Invoke native framework from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile-website

I have 2 different types doubts here. ( it is for all mobile device web app)

1. Is it possible to invoke native framework from Javascript in mobile web app? if so guide me any JS lib avilable?
2. Is it possible to invoke another web/native app from one mobile web app?

Thanks in advance,

sri

Answer (score 0):

In general no, you can't do this. If you build your app with PhoneGap it may be possible. Have a look at http://www.phonegap.com/.

BTW - you're currently posting a lot of questions related to mobileweb.  You will get better answers if you give more details on the devices you want to support, if you're developing something you want to distribute to consumers or to corporate workforce (where you control the devices). It would also help if you explain why you want to do the things you're asking - better solutions may be offered.